# how to get rid of header banner buttons on child themes

Tags: themes, buttons

I had just made my child theme yesterday which is dependent on the parent theme but i was wondering how do i get rid of the header banner buttons which i had inherited from the parents theme from the child theme? if someone could point in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

please find the link to my staging website for now: http://hoho25974.staging-cloud.partnerconsole.net/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my apologises.. I had found the answer to my questions...i forgotten that i had to go under customise to change the header options to omit the buttons. just had to choose none in the header options- header right block content. thanks for your help zakir

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly impossible to give you a solution without checking your parent theme header section code. But you can simply add a line of CSS `#site-banner-right { display: none; }` to hide that button.

Comment: thanks zakir... I found the inspect element, has a header button container... i know that if i hide the button it does the same thing but i would prefer to delete

`<div id="header-button-container">
                     <div id="header-button-container-inner">
                         <a href="/" class="button primary-button">Primary Button</a>
                      <a href="/" class="button secondary-button">Secondary Button</a>
                  </div>
                    </div>`
but i cant find the file that it hides in.. so that i could copy that file into my child theme and change it..

Comment: i tried what you suggested in the style.css file but the buttons is still there